# swagger-js: how to add authorization headers?

Tags: node.js, swagger

I'm trying to do something very simple: add api key authorization header in a post request. 
What I tried so far:

- add it under headers key in requestOptions
- add it when creating the client under authorization key

  - this is where the search space begins to expand: which key do I add? the security type `apiKey`? Whatever key I gave it in my spec? The actual header name? <strike>(none of those worked, btw)</strike>

Unfortunately, I could not find any helpful info in documentation (actually I could not find any documentation other than the [README](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/blob/master/README.md) and the [FAQ](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/blob/master/docs/MIGRATION_2_X.md) pages which do not provide disambiguation in this matter). 
So, any practical example and/or point to un/official docs that show how to work with this thing would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, from digging around in [swagger-js code](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/blob/master/src/execute/oas3/build-request.js#L125), *"Whatever key I gave it in my spec"* is the way to go. Meaning, if your security schemes look like this:

```yml
components:
  securitySchemes:
    ymlSpecAuthKeyName: # <-- also swagger-js key
      type: apiKey
      name: X-Auth-Header-Name
      in: header
```

and you want your request to look like this:

```sh
curl -X POST "http://your-api-url.com/doc-you-want-to-create" \
  -H  "X-Auth-Header-Name: api-key-header-value" \
  -H  "Content-Type: application/json" \ 
  -d "{\"json-request-body\": \"goes-here\"}"
```

Then you should make a swagger-js client like this:

```js
let client = await Swagger({
  spec: spec,
  authorizations: {
    ymlSpecAuthKeyName: 'api-key-header-value',
  }
});
```